# Page not reloading

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I have used mobile.js.  In my apps using phonegap for developing app

Please check my code

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PlayTradeWin</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

        <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>

        <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
          function onDeviceReady() {
              //some js code here
          }
        </script>
     </head>
<body>
<a href="login.html" data-transition="flip">Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PlayTradeWin</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

        <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
         <script>
              alert("Hello");
         </script>
     </head>
<body>
   Login form here..
</body>
</html>
```

My page  fliping perfectly but When I will going `index.html` to `login.html` by clicking of `Login` link in index.html page my JavaScript alert not working.

Comment: you are using jquery mobile, when you use jquery mobile you don't load the whole login.html page, just get the html content, if you want to execute code when the login.html page loads, there are events for that

Comment: Yes i am using that events. That also not working.

Comment: then, show your code

Comment: @jcesarmobile tell me how can i load by using of mobile events?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$( function() {
 alert('Hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this type of js script injection into HTML is not supported by Cordova. You need to do the logic in the index.js script.

Also if you wish to perform a alert you can use the apache cordova plug-in for notifications (you can get it via project config --> plugins).

Comment: Yes i have ued index.js

Comment: cordova plug-in not added in my project. Can you say me how to add this?

Comment: Did it work for you now or is there another problem?

Comment: are you working with visual studio? you need to double click "config.xml". there you will find a section where you can import cordova plugins ;)

Comment: There is no plugin inside the config.xml file

Comment: hmmm. then you should add eclipse tag into your question above ;)

Comment: Can you say me step by step how to add this?

Comment: you could try to add the plugin via npm.exe in console. does that work for you?